# generate class from xsd with xjc

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

i try to generate class from xsd but i got problem with the second line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:saqcc="urn:saq:cct:cct-3.5.xsd" xmlns:flx="urn:saq:mtl:grey:flux:04489:rep-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:saq:mtl:grey:flux:04489:rep-1.0.xsd"  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1">
```

...

i got this error:

> [ERROR] Content is not allowed in prolog.
>     so xjc seem to have problem with schema

this xsd have an import and in this import there is another import... so i don't know when the error will be removed if xjc will be able to manage that...

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and it turned out the encoding was the issue:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

works but

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

doesn't (at least on my Windows7/64 bit OS).

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved the issue, thanks. But still I do not understand the reason. Why wouldn't it work with utf-16?

Answer (score 2):

When I get this error with any sort of XML document, it's usually because of some (invisible) content before `<?xml`. More specifically, this is due to the BOM ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)) added by some editor. In my case, it was mostly due to this BOM: `ï»¿`

Check if you have such content in your file. If you do, remove it. XML files don't need a BOM, as they can formally specify the encoding in the prolog like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**UPDATE**: The prolog *MUST* be the first part of well-formed XML, as defined by w3c here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-well-formed

Comment: no only invisible char i have it's crlf ( carriage return, linefeed)

Comment: That's not permitted either. `<?xml` MUST be the first characters in an XML file, as you can see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-well-formed

Comment: i have nothing before <?xml  crlf it's for every end of line (like any other document...)